# How to achieve left join without where clause in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

`House.objects.filter(owner__isnull=True)` will produces following SQL:

```
SELECT "app_House"."id", "app_House"."name" FROM "app_House" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_Owner" ON ("app_House"."id" = "app_Owner"."house_id") 
WHERE "app_Owner"."id" IS NULL
```

Is there a syntax available to force Django to omit the *where* clause?

Comment: Why would you want to omit the where clause? It is exactly what you are asking in your filter.

Comment: @scharette: OP knows that way how to achieve LEFT JOIN, but probably wants it with both null and not null on the right hand.

Comment: Yes. Exactly as hynekcer mentioned. In my example, I want to get every house with the owner but also all houses that do not belong to anyone. In SQL simple left join would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select all houses without doing a database query each time you need informations about the owner.

For this Case the django-api hast the [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method. In your case you would have to use the following query:

```
House.objects.all().select_related('owner')
```

Comment: @pguzewicz It is still not clear what you want to do with owner. I started to write a general answer, but not continue. Maybe this short answer is enough.